# sp_executesql securing the dynamic search keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert the SQL statement to support the sp_executesql to make it safe but I ran into an unsafe area. Hopefully you guys can help me with this. I've created the temp table to make it easier to demonstrate the problem.

The problem is at STEP # 6. I can use the STEP # 5 BUT this is not safe and it can be hacked easily. I don't really want break the keywords and search multiple times because of the system performance.

Error for MS SQL 2008 Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ORDER'.

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ups_MultiWareHouse]    Script Date: 06/14/2012 09:12:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
create PROCEDURE ups_TestSearch(
@Keywords nvarchar(4000),
@SortColumns nvarchar(4000)
)
AS
--STEP #1 - Create Temp Table - Begin
    CREATE TABLE #TempTable 
    (
        ProductID uniqueidentifier,
        ProductName varchar(600),
        Price decimal(18,2),
        Active bit
    )

--STEP #2 - Insert couple records to search
    INSERT INTO #TempTable (ProductID,ProductName,Price,Active) VALUES(NEWID(),'Mouse','10.12','1')
    INSERT INTO #TempTable (ProductID,ProductName,Price,Active) VALUES(NEWID(),'Keyboard','20.45','1')
    INSERT INTO #TempTable (ProductID,ProductName,Price,Active) VALUES(NEWID(),'Monitor','150.87','0')--Disable this product

--STEP #3 - Display the current table data
        select 'STEP #3' as STEP,   * FROM #TempTable

--STEP #4 - SETTING UP sp_executesql to support parameter substitution
    --Set definition
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(4000);
    SET @ParmDefinition='
                        @Param1ProductName nvarchar(4000),
                        @Param2SortColumns nvarchar(4000)
                        '                   
    DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(4000);

--STEP #5-  CONVERT THE @SQLString TO use @Keywords and @SortColumns
    --Run query for the below like this ups_TestSearch'ProductName=''Mouse'' OR ProductName=''Keyboard''', 'Price DESC, ProductName ASC'
    SET @SQLString = N'SELECT ''STEP #5'' as STEP, #TempTable.*  FROM #TempTable WHERE ('+@Keywords+') ORDER BY '+@SortColumns;--unsafe, open to hackers
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @Param1ProductName = @Keywords, @Param2SortColumns=@SortColumns;

--STEP #6-  CONVERT THE @SQLString TO use @Keywords and @SortColumns
    --Run query for the below like this ups_TestSearch'ProductName=''Mouse'' OR ProductName=''Keyboard''', 'Price DESC, ProductName ASC'    
    SET @SQLString = N'SELECT ''STEP #6'' as STEP, #TempTable.*  FROM #TempTable WHERE (@Param1ProductName)  ORDER BY @SortColumns';--Safe but not working
    SELECT @SQLString AS SeeStatement
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @Param1ProductName = @Keywords, @Param2SortColumns=@SortColumns;

--Drop temp table
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Comment: How does #6 not work?  Is there an error?

Comment: Error for MS SQL 2008 Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ORDER'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that in Step 5 you aren't using parameter substitution - that is, you are basically building the SQL statement by string concatenation. When you execute it via sp_executesql you could really just do this:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SqlString
```

The code in Step 6 is performing parameter substitution. In this case, however, you are limited to using parameters only in locations where they are allowed in "normal" SQL expressions. For example, you can't do this in T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @Criteria NVARCHAR(500);
SET @Criteria = N' WHERE ProductName = ''Mouse'''
SELECT * FROM #MyTempTable + @Criteria
```

Depending upon how complex you expect your filter to be, you might be able to write the criteria to a temporary table and perform a join to the temporary table to limit the resulting data that is returned. Off the top of my head I am not sure how best to sort the resulting data unless you did that in the calling code perhaps?

Comment: You are right on the step #5. This step is just for the demo purpose of this code. I has nothing to do with the step #6.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that the `WHERE` clause in step 6 is invalid, and so is the `ORDER BY` clause. This is because you're passing in strings as parameters to `sp_executesql` and trying to use them as entire clauses. Additionally, the statement references a parameter `@SortColumns`, but you appear to have named the parameter `@Param2SortColumns`.

Have a read of what some SQL server MVPs have written:

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

More to the point: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/parameterizing-result-order

I don't see a simple way to alter your procedure to make this work, since you're passing in entire `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses as parameters. What you should really do is redesign the proc. Supply each `WHERE` criterion as an individual parameter to `ups_TestSearch`. You resupply each `WHERE` parameter to `sp_executesql` and structure your initial SQL statement in this fashion:

```
SET @SQLString = SELECT and JOIN portions of command
SET @SQLString = @SQLString + 'WHERE 1 = 1 '
  IF (@WhereParam1 IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQLString = @SQLString + 'AND (SomeTable.SomeColumn = @WhereParam1) '
  IF (@WhereParam2 IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQLString = @SQLString + 'AND (SomeTable.SomeColumn = @WhereParam2) '
  ...
```

If necessary, you can use the same structure to add joins to the statement.

The `ORDER BY` structure depends on how complex this might get, and whether you know all possible involved columns. If it's relatively simple, you can write it out as a `CASE` statement as follows, or break it up as individual parameters, as I recommend for the `WHERE` clause.

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@SortColumns, 'SortCol1') > 0 THEN SortCol1 ELSE NULL END,
  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@SortColumns, 'SortCol2') > 0 THEN SortCol2 ELSE NULL END,
  ...
```

The simplest thing to do here might be to sort at the application level rather than the DB, but that could be just as infeasible as a complex `ORDER BY` clause would be to parameterize.

Comment: i see, thank so much, i thought there are other way to handle this. Its look like I have to write a loop to handle this problem. Thanks so much